# There is no [value] left in this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) tag has 3089 questions, and 77 followers. It is used on a variety of questions, [primarily where the issue is that some variable, property, attribute, etc., is not set to the value that OP expects it to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184623/still-unsure-as-to-why-this-integer-remains-unmodified). I think that that particular issue could describe a large portion of all questions on SO.  Other situations are [a multi-valued function/process returning an unexpected number of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199457/neural-network-always-get-one-value) or [getting only the value from some structure like a key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207982/outputting-only-the-value-of-json-encode-object).

I think that for the lack of followers/good tag wiki, the relatively small amount of questions, and the lack of specificity for the questions it describes, it should be burninated.

Comment: Its better to upgrade this to a blacklist request as the current value tag was created around Jan 18,2015. The value tag was [once burninated](http://web.archive.org/web/20120811093515/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value)

Comment: Why do we need to spend effort on this again?, yes it has not much [value], no it's not doing any major damage and bulk removing will not add [value] to the questions. Black list bahh... people will try to add some other [value] as using [return-value], [key-value], [default-value] and the list goes on. Lets concentrate or efforts where we can really bring some [value] to SO

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: 112/-3. No answers.

Comment: Moderator Notes: 1. The tag has 1k+ posts, and therefore if it's decided to burninate, it will be a tag deletion and not the normal burnination.  2. As we're starting this on a Friday, it will remain [featured] through the weekend and would be decided on Tuesday.

Comment: What happened to all the blacklist punny titles? It feels like no-one cares anymore :-(

Comment: @MichaelBerry If you look at [the burninate proces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) you can see that punny titles get replaced in phase 2 (like here). But they are very much alive and most of the time returned when the proces is done. You can see it on [the previous one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340724/no-more-time-for-the-flaming-arrow)

Comment: @AndréKool Thanks, didn't realise that - I've clearly just seen more posts in phase 2 recently :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry Probably, because it's in phase 2 that the post gets featured.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: 173/-4. A1 saying Yes +32/-0. A2 saying Yes +25/-0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 35):

Good riddance!

Given the tag alone, I can see no reasonable defense of it. My guess is a few of the questions need to go to [value-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value-type) and a few more to [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) and a handful to [marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marshalling) (my browser says that tag is misspelled but that's what it is) and all the rest just need the tag removed or closed outright. There's a small chance of also finding a question that belongs in [constant-folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constant-folding) (which doesn't exist).

Since it's been burninated before, blacklist time.

So my guidance ended up being rather useless. Of all the ones I did I didn't find a single [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) or [value-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value-type) and only one or two [marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marshalling) but quite a few [key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value) and a ton of questions that had [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set) [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) when trying to set a value of a variable. The most common tag replacement was [key-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value) which came up a lot when a question had [key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key) and [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value).

Comment: Your browser must have been contaminated by American English if it thinks 'marshalling' is wrong.

Comment: Can you add some of these observations into the progress answer? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372872/4099593 thanks!

Comment: @BhargavRao: No. Some wise guy disable right-click copy. I can't select or copy anything from the textarea anymore.

Comment: Ah, k.  I didn't copy paste it directly because the answer is written as a explanation, which needs to be tailored into a guidance.

Answer (score 27):

I agree with this burnination request. Answering  [the 4 questions for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. It certainly does not describe the contents. We do not know about what value the OP is talking about. If it is the only tag on the question, then it would not be clear at all. It is ambiguous as well, as the questions tagged contain questions related to

   1. value of a variable
   2. HTML value attribute
   3. value of a key in a key-value store (like dictionaries).
   4. @Value annotation in Java
   5. Return value of a function
   6. r-value and l-value of variables

      ... and these are just from the first 5 pages. Therefore, we don't know as to which "value" the user wants to imply when they use the tag.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Partial No. Even though value itself is used for on-topic posts (like the multitude of different options), it needs another tag to remain on-topic and describe the contents of the question. Therefore I'm putting it as a partial no.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No. This is a big No, and the tag is just superfluous on many of the questions where it is used. It is being used almost as a meta tag, and does not add more information than what is already been present. With just the value tag and no other tag, we cannot figure out much about the question.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. It does not mean the same in all common contexts as well. The term value itself is inherently ambiguous and may have many meanings, like key-value, return value, l-value, etc, all of which should probably be different tags.

I don't necessarily agree with the premise that "the lack of followers/good tag wiki, the relatively small amount of questions, and the lack of specificity" are reasons for tags to be burninated (they can be used to support the cause of burninations), but given that this tag has a No answer for all the four questions, it should be burninated.

Comment: It would appear the burninate criteria is only a rough guideline anyway: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372805/14768 (net -2 right now)

Comment: @Joshua, it needs to be No for all. The second one is usually the problem. "Unobtrusive" there suffers from the same issue here, even though some of the concepts described are on-topic, but due to the ambiguity, the tag might possibly be used for other off-topic reasons. That's one reason why I put it as Partial No here. (Remember that if not for the 4 rules, [fix] would have been a candidate for burnination https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371686/4099593)

Answer (score 10):

[value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

## Progress:

The [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=value),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvalue%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvalue%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvalue%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvalue%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178477/burnination-progress-for-the-value-tag)

[image]

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) has more than 3000 questions. Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Somebody did a high-power tag delete. It didn't even edit the questions. That's quite the cliff function.

Comment: Probably some mod tool. Otherwise this burnination effort would be ongoing for the next 6 to 8 years...

Comment: Erm, @Luuklag, it's a CM tool. Check the Step 5 on the burnination procedure (for the large tags).

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry to butt in here, but the 5th step also mentions that the community wiki post should be edited to mention that the burnination is completed. I'd edit it myself (and it is community wiki) but the burnination process makes it clear that the *moderator* edits the answer. May I humbly request that you make the edit? Thanks!

Comment: @KenHilton It doesn't really matter much, anyone can edit the answer.