# Should we burninate the [fix] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070), is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system, but instead renamed to a more specific tag-name*

---

The [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) tag should be **burninated**.

Why? Take a look at the questions with that tag. They are all questions like "How can I fix this?"

In the first page of results, there was only **one** well received question. The rest were all 0 or negative.

[image]

Well let's take a look at why it was created in the first place:

> **Questions tagged [fix]**
>
> The Financial Information eXchange Protocol ( a "FIX Protocol" ) is a series of messaging specifications for the electronic communication of both trade-related and quote-stream related electronic trading messages between a market-access venue and a trading-desk operator ( be it a human or an ...

So it was created because of the Financial Information Exchange Protocol. Fair enough. However, in the first page of results, only half of them are actually related to the FIX Protocol. Everything else is just someone looking for a "fix" to their problem.

## My Solution:

---

**BURNINATE IT!!!** Do a quick tag clean up, rename the [fix] tag to [fix-protocol]. Now no one is going to say "Can someone help me [fix-protocol] my problem?", and the problem is solved!

Also for those of you who don't think this is necessary, see the answer here:

[I want to delete the [internet]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet)

You can also view this [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

Comment: Why not perform a tag clean-up then rename the tag? I see no reason to remove the tag from the system entirely, plus you would then lose all of the questions that are actually related to the FIX protocol.

Comment: It shows that people does not read the description attached to a given tag. Anyways, I would not burninate it but rename the tag and do some cleanup. There are only 410 questions (last checked on 2018-07-26 08:51 GMT+02)

Comment: Remember that tags can auto-complete.

Comment: I suggest the verbose version "financial-information-exchange-protocol"... is there a length limit?

Comment: Burninate === completely remove the tag from the system. If that is still what you're suggesting (as is indicated by the bold, all caps, and three exclamation marks), then I still disagree with the request.

Comment: As we're talking about naming here ... it's a [tag:rename-request] + [tag:cleanup]. [fix] needs to be renamed to [fix-protocol], and then the unwanted questions from there should be [clean(ed)up]. It's neither a [burnination-request] not a [retag-request]. But meh, don't focus much on the semantics, the end goal is the same.

Comment: @pnuts, if that's the case, then we should have a [tag:tag-disambiguation]. I will probably write a detailed answer later tonight.

Comment: @BhargavRao Could you grant the rename-request? Community will happily do the cleanup afterward.

Comment: @Cœur, I mentioned that only based on what the OP has written. However, according to pnuts, looks like there are a few more tags which are being confused. I'll check them out and then let you know, in a few hours.

Comment: As the little [Tiny Giant suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371594/the-fix-is-broken?cb=1#comment614197_371594) [tag:fix] should become [tag:fix-protocol].

Comment: The `fix` tag is properly used mostly AFAICT, renaming to `fix-protocol` is better than removing it.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +49/-13. A1 (saying yes) +2/-3. A2 (saying no) +11/-2

Comment: @BhargavRao last time [you draw a line in the sand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383150/this-tag-invariably-needs-to-be-burninated/384214#comment691253_384214) that as long as the tag was removed, it has to be a burnination request. You promised a post explaining the differences, but haven't seen that one yet.

Comment: @BhargavRao I upvoted the question, because it is a relevant question. My upvote was neither for or against burnination, and neither for or against renaming. I am interested in effective statistics to see how many times the fix tag was misused (if that is even possible). If it is misused a lot, I would vote for renaming.

Comment: What's really confusing me is that this is a burnination request in name, but the solution proposed is *BURNINATE IT!!! Do a quick tag clean up, rename the [fix] tag to [fix-protocol]*. Here I can see somewhat of a contradiction since renaming is not the same as burninating.

Comment: @Braiam, I've not been in the best of free times of late, which is why I've not found time to write it up. I will surely write one up. If you want to see an equivalent to this, [tag:jetbrains] was a similar case. (Also my previous comment up there - Jul 26'18 - is wrong, so don't follow that. I wasn't aware of some stuff back then)

Comment: @TT., I don't have any stats on that, but from what I can see none of it seem to be about fixing as such. However, Braiam claims that there were a few that were edited in their answer, which we can probably use as a starting point to find more.

Comment: @apokryfos the question might have somewhat confused wording (the original asked to burn [fix] and create a new [fix-protocal] tag); but the decision about what to do is based on answer voting not if the original question asked for a burn, a major cleanup, a retag, or something else.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +86/-21. A1 (saying yes) +6/-4. A2 (saying no) +32/-7 A3 (saying rename) +21/-1. A3 seems the least controversial. The community has voted in favor of swapping the synonym direction and making [fix-protocol] the main tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao Now that I read correctly your comment, I'm not saying yes to the burnination. I'm explicitly on the rename: A cleanup is warranted, to make sure there isn't off topic questions, then proper re-tagging for those that aren't about the protocol and **then a rename** to make sure people looking for a fix doesn't use the tag. That was even on my original answer, with the pun intact.

Comment: @Braiam, ah, cool. I think I misread your answer. Anyway, the consensus was on renaming, so I guess my mistake didn't have a wrong impact. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm going to propose a slight variation on Bhargav's answer. Again, looking at the tag Wiki:

> The Financial Information eXchange Protocol ( a "FIX Protocol" ) is a series of messaging specifications for the electronic communication of both trade-related and quote-stream related electronic trading messages between a market-access venue and a trading-desk operator ( be it a human or an algorithmic-trading engine ).

The tag Wiki itself appears to unambiguously identify a programming topic, so it would be wrong to fully burninate. With that said, [people don't read the tag usage guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-should-we-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio). This fact is shown by how widely-misused the tag is.

I say we clean up the tag and then rename it. Get rid of the bad questions, remove the tag from everything that's not related to the FIX Protocol, and rename the tag to [fix-protocol].

Comment: Why rename a tag when it isn't needed? I checked the entire list of questions today again, and all of them are related to the fix protocol itself. If the tag was being misued a lot, then probably a rename would have been necessary, but here it isn't even needed.

Comment: @BhargavRao because people are investing their time fixing the usage instead of answering questions. When [I answered this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371682/792066), you need to exclude the obvious correct ones, since those are ~650 vs ~450, so it's very likely to a fix tagged question that has quickfix[n,j]? but not the other way. I searched recently deleted and retagged ones and was able to find more in the last year.

Comment: @BhargavRao: It *is* needed to reduce the frequency of clueless newbies tagging their questions with it.  **SO tag names need to account for human nature and the prevalence of new and inexperienced users.**  Avoid common English words that people might use as tags.  Especially when that's easily possible without making things worse for actual users of the tag.  It will auto-complete easily.  Anyone following that tag will be glad their results aren't polluted with new bad questions.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "widely misused" part here. I've been checking the "fix" tag somewhat frequently since this topic was posted and have removed the tag from about five (think no more than ten, not sure) questions.

Comment: @TT. because those cases are either deleted or retagged and deleted. Remember, the questions that misuse this tag are usually grossly off topic, that are quickly deleted. The query I used in my answer showed that questions are deleted in hours.

Comment: @BhargavRao [The new question tagged with this is off-topic and has nothing to do with the FIX Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022312/ubuntu-binds-escape-key-to-unmute-mute-the-internal-mic).

Comment: @TT. You're missing a pretty big point: we can avoid misuse *entirely* with a tag rename. Remember, very few people pay attention to excerpts and so they tend to use whatever tag they can throw in. Saying "It doesn't happen often" isn't the same as saying "It never happens". Why keep letting new users make the mistake of using this tag when we can stop them before they ever get there? [This rename proves better tag names work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym)

Comment: @EJoshuaS That's by chance I suppose. I wouldn't mind seeing statistics to back the "wide misuse" claim. Otherwise, it's just another opinion. In any case, I'm not arguing against renaming the tag just so we're clear ;-).

Comment: @TT.: We have something like a 50% mistag rate. Probably more because the stupid way I gathered it has a high false negative rate.

Answer (score 21):

I disagree with the [burnination-request](/questions/tagged/burnination-request), as the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371682/4099593) and others in comments have already mentioned.

Going one by one on the burnination check-list:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  Yes, it does. Questions which contain any issues about the FIX Protocol needs to be tagged [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix). From the excerpt:

  > The Financial Information eXchange Protocol ( a "FIX Protocol" ) is a series of messaging specifications for the electronic communication of both trade-related and quote-stream related electronic trading messages between a market-access venue and a trading-desk operator ( be it a human or an algorithmic-trading engine ).

  which is quite clear. It is unambiguous as well, given that there are no multiple fix protocols which makes the question asker confused about what to tag when they're concerned about one of the many fix protocols.
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Yes, FIX is a [communication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol), and programming questions about it is completely valid on the site. In fact it is one of the [most famous electronic trading protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_electronic_trading_protocols). (If you are requesting to burninate the fix protocol because of it's not on-topicness, then you might as well request to burninate [tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcp), on which most of the internet runs).
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Yes, it adds meaningful information to the post in a way. The usage of [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) makes it sure that the question is using the FIX protocol.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No, this is the only "no" answer to the list. The common context includes the purpose of fixing bad questions. There are quite a few questions misusing the tag [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) to post non fix-protocol related questions.

If the answer is yes, to just one of these 4 questions, it is clear reason enough to not burninate the tag. Here, the answer is yes to 3 of them and is quite evident that we should not be burninating the tag.

Adding to all of this, is the [comment by one of the top users of the tag, which clearly asks not to burninate the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371594/the-fix-is-broken#comment614606_371594) (and top users of the tag are given higher priority over others).

Also, from a [now deleted post:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371618/4099593)

> Of 398 Open Qs tagged [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) there are very strong signs that at least 215 instances have the tag inline with the Usage guide quoted above. (215 Open Qs tagged both [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix) and [quickfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quickfix).) A quick glance indicates that *most* others relate to the FIX protocol also.

This clearly shows that a [cleanup](/questions/tagged/cleanup) is needed and not a burnination. People misusing a tag, shouldn't be a reason to burninate a tag, it's enough reason to clean it up. Remember that some guy once tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) because he wanted to draw a python in HTML. People misuse tags all the time, and it's our duty to correct them and teach them the right way to use the tags.

Comment: "People misusing a tag, shouldn't be a reason to burninate a tag" If we have to keep cleaning it, obviously, something should be done such that the work doesn't have to be repeated.

Comment: "Remember that some guy once tagged python because he wanted to draw a python in HTML." Sometimes, a renaming is in order. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575

Comment: @pnuts I *always* prefer preventing. I don't care if there's evidence that we don't have to do work, I want to have the certainty that there *will never be*. Call it the rule for the lazy: if you don't want to spend effort, spend as little as possible making sure that you don't have to.

Comment: @Braiam let's clean it up for now, and then again have a look at the tag a month down the line. If it has again become messy, then it certainly is grounds for renaming. As of now, just with a few questions are wrongly tagged.

Comment: Tangentially related - does a tag rename come with the 1500 rep requirement to re-create the original tag?

Comment: @JiriTousek tag renames can only be done by diamond mods.

Comment: That's not what I meant - AFAIK if we delete a tag, it then requires higher rep user to re-create it than if it never existed before? Is that correct? If so, is this the same with tags that have been renamed (here I mean the original name)?

Comment: @JiriTousek, Once a tag has been deleted, it needs the same rep requirement to re-create the same tag (1500). So if a tag say [foo] has been renamed to [bar], then a user needs 1500 rep to recreate [foo].

Comment: @Braiam I agree - let's rename it. I [suggest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384671/4032703) that in my answer if so that people can vote on it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS what's the difference between what you propose and what I proposed?

Comment: @Braiam It's similar. It was more as a way to let people vote on it, since it's different than this answer. I can make mine a CW or delete mine so that you can post instead if you'd prefer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm merely asking, since you specifically pinged me to see your answer.

Comment: @Braiam Since the comment was old and this is just now featured, I figured it made sense for someone to add an answer so that people can vote on it.

Comment: How the heck did you come to the conclusion that a tag named [tag:fix] is unambiguous? I would have *never* guessed it meant a very domain specific protocol named FIX from the name. This is further supported by misuse of the tag documented in the question, where the tag is being conflated with the idea of fixing a problem (which is honestly what I would have guessed is the main use of the tag). [tag:fix-protocol], as mentioned in the question, is clear enough, but [tag:fix] is clearly not.

Comment: I agree with @jpmc26 - this tag should be renamed to prevent us from having to deal with people misusing it, and to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fix+-quickfix+-quickfixj), I was able to find at least 4 questions in the list of 15, which isn't really about the FIX protocol itself, but something else. 3 were off topic even when they asked about something related to the protocol itself and at least 1 was about a third party api that speak the protocol, but somehow OP manages to receive no response from the server, which is a problem using the server api, not the protocol itself.

The tag doesn't look good if the 15 most recent questions have about 40% of questions with questionable use of the tag. A cleanup is warranted, to make sure there isn't off topic questions, then proper re-tagging for those that aren't about the protocol and then a rename to make sure people looking for *a fix* doesn't use the tag.

Examples of recent question using fix as in repairing instead of the protocol:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469289/how-to-fix-intel-ssd-8mb-bug-using-linux-terminal
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206297/sony-vio-laptop
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033130/how-do-i-repair-my-linux-mint-repositories

Sadly, can't see revision history of deleted questions, these are the most  recent ones that are still not deleted in the site:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54971149/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53685179/revisions