# Change tag Cirrus to Adobe-Cirrus

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I'm working with [Cirrus CI](https://cirrus-ci.org/) - a tool for continuous build. When I searched Stack Overflow for some help on that topic, I stumbled upon [cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus), and that confused me. Is there a chance to rename [cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus) to something like [adobe-cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-cirrus) and create another tag `cirrus-ci` to prevent the mixup?

See *[Cirrus CI notify email on failed build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035830/cirrus-ci-notify-email-on-failed)*.

Comment: if there are any questions that already are related to cirrus-ci, feel free to create the new tag. See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: referring to your supposed action: create one, how do i know i there is a real need for it? i'm not sure if there is a community (at least a small community) for cirrus-ci...

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "if there are any questions", sorry about that (edited). If there are a few on-topic questions about the tag already, then it means that there is a need for the tag. Once we create a tag, and once it becomes famous, a community will soon start building up.

Comment: i don't find any questions concerning that topic

Comment: If that's the case, then we wait until there are questions related to that topic. As of now, we can just rename the tag to use [adobe-cirrus], and move on.

Comment: i think that would already be a great help (at least for me - a single cirrus-ci user, hahaha)... thank you very much for taking my problems serious!!!!

Comment: I'll try to compile my comments into an answer and wait for the community at large to decide. Also, we take every tag related issues seriously, so you don't need to worry that you're the only user.

Comment: that has been a very conforming conversation! this was my first post on stackOverflow Meta! i'll keep an eye on the progress of this topic! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As I was mentioning in the comments on the post, creating a new tag has a few rules to be followed. They are listed out in this meta FAQ post: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work). If there are on-topic questions related to a particular tag, feel free to add a new tag, and suggest a good excerpt along with usage guidance.

However, in this particular case, there is also the scenario of Cirrus being used for the Adobe-Cirrus product, and hence we need to disambiguate the usage of the original tag.

I went through all the 51 questions tagged [cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus). Apart from just, Adobe-cirrus, and cirrus-CI which you mention, I see a couple other usages:

- Delphi Prism Cirrus (1 post - [Delphi Prism Cirrus accessing and setting the Result of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949385/delphi-prism-cirrus-accessing-and-setting-the-result-of-a-function))
- Cirrus HPC service, (2 posts - [how to install kcachegrind on linux or cirrus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307239/how-to-install-kcachegrind-on-linux-or-cirrus), [rm -rf (remove) command does not work for too-deeply-nested folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091992/rm-rf-remove-command-does-not-work-for-too-deeply-nested-folders))

Usually, I prefer to not rename the tag, if I see a majority of questions about the same concept, and instead retag the handful of ones that aren't. However, coming fresh from the [burnination of the [fix] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371594/should-we-burninate-the-fix-tag), where it was decided to make tag names more meaningful as-is, I propose the following:

- Use [adobe-cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-cirrus) for the Adobe Cirrus product. We synonymize [cirrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus) to this tag.
- Use [cirrus-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus-ci) for questions related to the Cirrus CI, if there is a need.
- Use the already present [delphi-prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-prism) for the Delphi Prism cirrus related question.
- Use [cirrus-hpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cirrus-hpc) for the questions related to the Cirrus HPC service

Comment: i agree - it seems sufficent enough to create a `cirrus-ci` tag. that creates enough "distance" to the already used `cirrus` tag. as mentioned before i'm still not sure if there is enough need to create such a tag, but i'll stick with this topic and maybe sooner or later i'll create this tag (i'm not afraid of doing so)

Comment: funny thing - i read about burnitating the `fix`tag just before, then saw it in your answer!

Comment: Yeah, it is never a problem to wait a couple of days before taking any action. Slow and steady wins the race.

Comment: hei - you just added the cirrus-ci tag =) you were faster than i was! Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, we need to add a good tag excerpt for it.

Comment: i've added some content into the tag description yet my reputation is not high enough to commit these directly - could you have an eye on that at some time?